# spa weight of 4,250 lbs

Tags: floor

I have a pre-existing patio and would like to add a spa tub which weighs 4,250 lbs filled with water. Unknow is, re-enforced with re-bar? the exposed one side appears to be at least 18 inches thick. What is the minimum thickness of normal concrete to hold that much weight, with or without re-bar?
?

Comment: I have seen hot tubs put on 2” slabs with no problem, the weight is spread over a large area and there are really no point loads. As far as 18” I doubt that it may have been a monolithic pour. But as long as on the ground it should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have mine on a 4" thick reinforced concrete pad, no problem. If not reinforced, I'd go with 6". Basic cheap "Quickcrete" is 3,000PSI compressive force, plenty strong enough when you factor in the surface area of the tub's structure that will be contacting the slab.

Keep in mind though that concrete strength takes a long time to get to the peak strength levels. So don't place your tub and start filling it immediately.

Age  vs Strength percent

- 1 day    16%
- 3 days   40%
- 7 days   65%
- 14 days  90%
- 28 days  99%

Oh wait, you said it was already existing... never mind.